# How to sort liberally-deep list of lists and integers?

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

Let's say I have a list like that:

```
[[5, [2, 1], 3], [3, [8, 7], [2, 1, 3], 2], [[3, 2, 1], 3, -1]]
```

(each list can store unspecified number of integers and lists in any order).
Rules for sorting:

- integers (if any) should be before any list
- integers are sorted normally (from lower to higher value)
- list is "smaller" than another when the first element is lower, if the same we consider the second element, the third, and so on.
- If the list has the same values as another but less, it's smaller. `[1, 2] < [1, 2, 3]`

So the final result should be:

```
[[-1, 3, [1, 2, 3]], [2, 3, [1, 2, 3], [7, 8]], [3, 5, [1, 2]], ]
```

How to implement that kind of sorting? I've tried to pass recursive function as `sort` key in `sorted`, but mostly ended with TypeError (`<` not supported for `int` and `list`).

Another example:

```
[1, 4, 3, [[5, 7, 1, 2], 2, 5, 10, 2], 8, [2, 5, [5, 3, 3]], [2, 5, 10, 2, [1, 2, 5]]]
```

After sorting :

```
[1, 3, 4, 8, [2, 2, 5, 10, [1, 2, 5]], [2, 2, 5, 10, [1, 2, 5, 7]], [2, 5, [3, 3, 5]]]
```

Comment: Because the first is a shorter list of size `3` and the second is a longer list of size `4`. Basically, list length has a higher precedence than list value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to compare sibling structures (i.e., deeply nested values inside the same list) correctly, safely and efficiently, is to decorate everything and *keep* it decorated until all the sorting is done. Then undecorate everything at the end. This doesn't modify the given structure but builds a sorted new one:

```
def deepsorted(x):
    def decosorted(x):
        if isinstance(x, int):
            return 0, x
        return 1, sorted(map(decosorted, x))
    def undecorated(x):
        islist, x = x
        if islist:
            return list(map(undecorated, x))
        return x
    return undecorated(decosorted(x))
```

Another way is to not rely on natural comparisons but use an old-style `cmp` function instead. This sorts in-place:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def deepsort(x):
    def cmp(a, b):
        if isinstance(a, int):
            if isinstance(b, int):
                return a - b
            return -1
        if isinstance(b, int):
            return 1
        diffs = filter(None, map(cmp, a, b))
        return next(diffs, len(a) - len(b))
    key = cmp_to_key(cmp)
    def sort(x):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            for y in x:
                sort(y)
            x.sort(key=key)
    sort(x)
```

Testing code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVXtjpswEPzvp9ifIDnVES5KVIlX6AtY6ESIaVETG4HTwtOnu/4Ak3DS1RIK3p2dHY9t0k3ml1b5qesfj4ts4CJlN@jeyEsypt8Z4HDhWj@FabQNtEOrBlOpWiYjh1aZKE2jl@beK3jjMLKnWMbBc96qLllaIDRN59Z3RZm@euk9XNvBIBaKiNoqosSmCkrYZhHp0i0COkI/iRWsjEgZY02vb9DcVW20vg7Q3jrMQn3rPoz@@C0nxmJbV6YiKKk4nD81tNoydA05b0Ei7RXs4LxlxS5j/8EYdmwOXtqmGdD5pr0a2Sc/tJIcyFlcFAe7qhdTlRxNYgs5XKVKqhTF0UvAol1IuXhHZMtBWPm3efpoe5@EN7qHCRcE46tFlnBKV/Hxm41i8wIfl/ONw2bXupvCPtO@0pwxIwdDhghbkghx4CD2HLKSQ46PyPE5cTiWPu7Ce5pSLkA57kxZcidKiF1mYyKziLz01XEIX48cTqVvcvApmpcpZ14Pht5dHSk7WgHUfG8rsjc3Ozl64jhY9NwxgObGh3KR6US@z/ULfgF/liFLlh60gtyRL9qF10q/Yh/1fUlENRuj3Boz11cL4h7BaDEriPg2kk@1bjFhHV@v9YcnoDbcyC2@xCOLF@Bn@0cqDn8rhd8tugz2sLoLYU9zMR/kxGLDpfMfLUq4UNfjtyGJ/iQcHIrCs/PoNjnqkEkfj38)):

```
from copy import deepcopy

tests = [
    ([[5, [2, 1], 3], [3, [8, 7], [2, 1, 3], 2], [[3, 2, 1], 3, -1]],
     [[-1, 3, [1, 2, 3]], [2, 3, [1, 2, 3], [7, 8]], [3, 5, [1, 2]], ]),

    ([1, 4, 3, [[5, 7, 1, 2], 2, 5, 10, 2], 8, [2, 5, [5, 3, 3]], [2, 5, 10, 2, [1, 2, 5]]],
     [1, 3, 4, 8, [2, 2, 5, 10, [1, 2, 5]], [2, 2, 5, 10, [1, 2, 5, 7]], [2, 5, [3, 3, 5]]]),

    ([[1, 2], [1, [2]]],
     [[1, 2], [1, [2]]]),

    ([[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]],
     [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]),

    ([[[1, 2]], [[1, [2]]]],
     [[[1, 2]], [[1, [2]]]]),

    ([[[1, [2]]], [[1, 2]]],
     [[[1, 2]], [[1, [2]]]]),

    ([[1, 3], [1, 2]],
     [[1, 2], [1, 3]]),
]

for given, wanted in tests:
    copy = deepcopy(given)
    deepsort(copy)
    print(deepsorted(given) == wanted,
          copy == wanted)
```

Comment: Wow, that is short (and probably effective). Checked for other cases too.

Comment: I was in a middle of debugging this. For now will accept Marek version, write if you have something.

Comment: Marek's solution is also broken for that case.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz I replaced it with two ways that I think work well. This is surprisingly tricky.

Comment: Yes, I thought "ok, I need those relationships in always the same order, got nested ids... it should be easy to order it" then noone in company knew how to do it :)
Checked for all my cases (not many). Seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Quick draft:

```py
def big_brain_sort(li: list) -> list:
    list_with_int = []
    list_with_list = []
    for el in li:
        if isinstance(el, int):
            list_with_int.append(el)
        elif isinstance(el, list):
            list_with_list.append(big_brain_sort(el))
    sorted_list_int = sorted(list_with_int)
    for lista in sorted(list_with_list, key=lambda x: (big_brain_sort(x), len(x))):
        sorted_list_int.append(lista)
    return sorted_list_int
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Seems the code does what I need. Nice `lambda` "trick" with a tuple.

Comment: You should, however fix the indentation.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz I don't think that lambda is nice. If I'm not mistaken, that key function has no effect whatsoever except for wasting time (potentially a lot). [Simplified version](https://tio.run/##jVDtaoQwEPyfp9ifhsZS9UQ5sC8i4fBqvAYkSkxb@vQ2u/HrrhQaCGR3Z2ZnMn6798Fk5WjnuVUdXPXtcrWNNpdpsC7q9Rl6PTkO8Ss9zgz80cZNUEEtqcL@oewGC6r3GD8IcKJ0oCdtJteYNxWpXqAI3@er7HMzjsq0HsG3mep/s8nVPZ18rPyHIF4u6FnlPqwBbKo2wo0cntaSFDhjN/2pDCaqcwF1KiCRAjJ/68zfUkAhl35op1jibIUKiBMp2VdjvCwJxQm164RAmVwEji3/LASUctmTLyOsJWOj9WYfY5FRDlUFYdXRu@eewgJMUZBZNJqSdPISqjL4wGU5oTdrK2hzmMu7SCHQaZPYKTv@rwn@4L4G02aL/j9zzvMP).

Comment: @KellyBundy Could you explain more what you mean? It works for the tests from the topic. I've checked that lambda with `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]` also and it is sorting properly.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz I'm not saying it doesn't work. I'm saying it does pointless repeat work.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz So for example it takes [~6 seconds](https://tio.run/##dZDdTsMwDIXv@xS@bKSBJrhBlcaLoClyqbtZBDdKg9ievsTJfiAVucmJfXT8Of4cj5M8v/iwLAON0PPB9gFZ7DyF2DruwPEcDTy8ZtE1kI4q@83xaFki7OBtX5VV3evjFIAcsCRHCdDDI/DMMkeUd2rJbZIhmnt/NegRvScZktXcTOTWMRn4vxxV16Bq2ZRbgvVFQ7ZeFiyV9g@Oue2mZdT1VjZVG/ig887hZz8gnDqox55MQiZJt/lFXTFckfOoMjlQ/ApSG5sGy8crmFWogHKg9ml7Cc9t3Dc@JHebsiocNMvyAw) to sort `[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]`. Calling the function over two million times in the process.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ok. I understood "that key function has no effect" differently (no effect = it is not sorting)

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz Ah, ok. No, I meant "no effect" as in "whether you use that key function or not, the result is the same". The *key function* has no effect. The *sorting* still does.

Comment: It's not working for `[[1, 2], [1, [2]]]`